# How to find $\gcd(n+1, n^2+7)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I've tried to use the rule that if $ b>a$, then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,b−a)$, as well as the properties of divisibility by adding and subtracting the terms from each other but haven't been able to reach a conclusion.

Comment: If $d\mid n+1$ and $d\mid n^2+7$, then $d\mid n^2+7-(n+1)(n-1)=8$

Comment: Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: $n^2+7=(n+1)^2-2(n+1)+8$

Comment: Just adding onto J.W. Tanner and Bumblebee's answer, if you want to find the gcd from "gcd divides $8$", you consider the cases of $n$ modulo $8$.

Comment: **Do not change your question after it has been answered**.  If you have a separate question, then post another question.  If you make edits to your question after it is answered that changes the substance of the question, you make the answer meaningless.  This violates the Community Guidelines.  Any such edits will be rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $d = \gcd (n+1,n^2+7)$. Then $d|n+1$ and $d|n^2+7$.
$$n^2+7 = n^2 + n - n + 7 = n(n+1) - (n-7)$$
So, $$d|n^2+7 \implies d|n(n+1) - (n-7) \implies d| n-7$$
since $d|n+1$ and hence $d|n(n+1)$. Now,
$$d|n-7 \text{ and } d|n+1  \implies d|n+1 - n + 7 \implies d|8$$
and we have $d|8$. Got it?

Comment: How do you go from $d|n(n+1) - (n-7)$ to $d| n-7$? In general, $d\mid a-b\to d\mid-b$. For example $3\mid4-1$ but $3\not\mid-1$.

Comment: I used the fact that $d|n+1$, hence $d|n(n+1)$. Note that if $d|a-b$ and $d|a$ then $d|b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\gcd(n+1,n^2+7)=\gcd(n+1,-n+7)=\gcd(n+1,8)$$
If $n=8k+r,$ this equals $\gcd(r+1,8).$

• I used that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b+ka).$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: We can alway construct number n in terms of prime p such the $n+1$ and $n^{2k}+p$ have a common divisor like $d=p+1$, we may write:

$n=m(p+1)-1\rightarrow n+1=m(p+1)$

$n^{2k}+p= M[p(m+1)]+1+p= t(p+1)$

where $M[p(m+1)]$ means a multiple of $p(m+1)$. In your question $p=7$, so any number of the form $n=8m-1$ gives $n+1=8m$ and $(8m-1)^2+7=8t$ such that common divisor becomes $p+1=7+1=8$. Hence $n+1$ and $n^2+p$ for particular values of n can have common divisor.